# Python check if a input has a digit in it?

Tags: python, string, input, numbers, python-3.4

Im trying to see how i can see if a number is in a users input. i tried using `.isdigit()` but only works if its just a number. im trying to add it to a password checker. i also tried `.isalpha()` but didn't work. what have i done wrong and what do i need to add or change?

here is what i have

```
   password = input('Please type a password ')
   str = password
   if str.isdigit() == True:

    print('password has a number and letters!')
    else:
            print('You must include a number!')`
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: @vinash-raj answered your question, but you really should consider https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn (or https://github.com/dropbox/python-zxcvbn for the Python version) for your use case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a generator expression and an `isdigit()` within the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function :

```
if any(i.isdigit() for i in password) :
       #do stuff
```

The advantage of using `any` is that it doesn't traverse the whole string and will return a bool value if it finds a digit for the first time!

It is equal to the fallowing function :

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try `re.search`

```
if re.search(r'\d', password):
     print("Digit Found")
```

And don't use builtin data types as varible names.